# Prove that every homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $(x,y)\rightarrow ax+by$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for a good starting point. I have a decent understanding of undergrad group theory.

Comment: is $Z$ the set of integers($\mathbb{Z}$)?

Comment: @choco_addicted yep

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793561/homomorphism-from-mathbbz-oplus-mathbbz-2-to-mathbbz)

Answer (score 3):

$f(x,y)=f(x,0)+f(0,y)=xf(1,0)+yf(0,1)$.